# Wrong AlternativeAttributes "Key" values returned

Tags: here-api

I am working with HERE geocoder and found that when using strictlanguagemode=true the values returned in AlternativeAttributes are always displaying the same "Key", mixing alternative names for multiple level objects.

For example, this request:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=....&app_code=....&language=en&strictlanguagemode=true&country=Spain&city=Palma
```

returns this response (as you can see, all AlternativeAttributes use the "Key":"city", but the response is mixing alternative names for the state, county and city:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2019-04-16T15:50:30.385+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "MatchLevel": "city",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "City": 1
            },
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_It18KKa.DRNOAE.IP7p2rD",
              "LocationType": "point",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 39.57149,
                "Longitude": 2.64694
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 39.57149,
                  "Longitude": 2.64694
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 39.65717,
                  "Longitude": 2.56391
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 39.50374,
                  "Longitude": 2.84777
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "Palma, Balearic Islands, Spain",
                "Country": "ESP",
                "State": "Balearic Is",
                "County": "Balearic Islands",
                "City": "Palma",
                "PostalCode": "07012",
                "AlternativeAttributes": [
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Illes Balears",
                    "Type": "baseName",
                    "Language": "CAT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balear Uharteak",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "BAQ"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Bale\u00e1rsk\u00e9 Ostrovy",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "CZE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearerne",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "DAN"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearen",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "DUT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Baleaarit",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "FIN"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Iles Bal\u00e9ares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "FRE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearische Inseln",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "GER"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Isole Baleari",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "ITA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Illes Balears",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "MAY"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearene",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "NOR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Baleary",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POL"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Ilhas Baleares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "\u0411\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0430\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u041e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "RUS"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Islas Baleares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SPA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearerna",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SWE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearske Ostrovy",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "CZX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Baleary",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearskie Ostrova",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "RUX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Illes Balears",
                    "Type": "baseName",
                    "Language": "CAT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearen",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "DUT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Iles Bal\u00e9ares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "FRE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearische Inseln",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "GER"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Isole Baleari",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "ITA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearene",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "NOR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Ilhas Baleares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Islas Baleares",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SPA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Balearerna",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SWE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Type": "baseName",
                    "Language": "CAT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma de Mallorca",
                    "Type": "baseName",
                    "Semantics": "synonym",
                    "Language": "CAT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "BAQ"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "\u5e15\u5c14\u9a6c",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "CHI"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "CZE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "DAN"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "DUT"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "FIN"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "FRE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "GER"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "\u03a0\u03ac\u03bb\u03bc\u03b1",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "GRE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "ITA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "\ud314\ub9c8",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "KOR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "MAY"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "NOR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POL"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POR"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "\u041f\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043c\u0430",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "RUS"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SPA"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "SWE"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "CZX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "GRX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "KOX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Palma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "POX"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Pa Er Ma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "PYN"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "city",
                    "Value": "Pal'ma",
                    "Semantics": "exonym",
                    "Language": "RUX"
                  }
                ],
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Spain",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Balearic Islands",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Balearic Islands",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this a Bug in the AlternativeAttributes response?
How should we differentiate between alternative names for state, county and city in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for alternative city name of Palma? If yes, alternative city names for Palma can be differentiate with Semantics and Language value.

Comment: For example exonym for Palma is Balearerne in Danish.

Comment: Well, not exactly. That is the exonym for Balearic Islands, which is the state, not the city Palma. In the AlternativeAttributes there are exonyms of the city, county and state, all mixed and referenced with the same "city" key value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should return exonym results with different keys which are city , country, state and county if available. We will check this. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder API now returns exonym results with different keys which are city , country, state and county when the option `strictlanguagemode` set to true.